# jQuery DataTable Excel Export password protected or export inside a protected ZipFile

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

Is there a way to set a password when exporting data from datable?
I could not find any data online regarding this matter online

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myTable").DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: "excel",
        password: "test",
      },
      {
        extend: "csv",
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

Comment: Example implementation is as below:

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'Export Excel',
        action: function (e, dt, button, config) {
          window.location.href = '/export/excel';
        },
      }, 'pdf', 'print',
    ],
  });
});

Then have a function to generate the excel in your server code and define a password for it, server code will depend on what language you are using